# Using new Azure Developer Portal, how to add a button on index that is conditional on if user is logged in?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Im using the new Azure APIMS Developer Portal, and notice that by default buttons show in the UI for unauthenticated users.

Is it possible to have buttons be conditional using the default editor?
Or is it required to take matters into my own hands and clone the repo/self host the app, and customize?

This is the repo
https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal

Comment: Hi. I think you need to custom the portal. Regarding how to custom portal, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal

Answer (score 0):

1. A dynamic menu (based on whether user is signed in) is coming soon: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/77
2. If you want to implement other conditional content (including buttons), you need to use the self-hosted option and edit widgets based on a context object.